# How to view basic MySQL metrics. Queries per second etc

Tags: mysql

Not sure how but is there a way to get basic metric data from MySQL. Show processlist list is a snap shot if now. But I was looking for average stats for a time frame. Last 10 minutes etc. I am using MySQL 8 on unbuntu 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

However, there are many issues.  You need to, for example, know that `Queries` or `Questions` is a count of queries (in/out of stored procs) since the server was restarted.  And that `Uptime` is in seconds.  Hence, division is needed for "per second".

Dozens need that division; dozens are in bytes; dozens are in numbers (`Max_used_connections`)

But...  That is only from start.  To get the "last 10 minutes", you needed to have captured value(s) 10 minutes ago.  That is not automatically available.  Various monitoring services (many cost money) do that for you.

(The above information applies to all versions.)

Answer (score 2):

Command `STATUS;` will return a brief summary for uptime and average q/s value. More comprehensive data returned by `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`